# ckeditor:Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/lang/en.php')

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting the following error from server:

> **Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/lang/en.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/38/8264638/html/console/assets/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php on line 16**

In my ckeditor i integrate the imageuploader and its working in my local server but its not working in hosted server.its saying error in imagebrowser.php file following are the code in imagebrowser.php..please help me..

```
<?php
session_start();
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$root = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";

// checking lang value
if(isset($_COOKIE['sy_lang'])) {
    $load_lang_code = $_COOKIE['sy_lang'];
} else {
    $load_lang_code = "en";
}

// including lang files
switch ($load_lang_code) {
    case "en":
        require(__DIR__ . '/lang/en.php');
        break;
    case "pl":
        require(__DIR__ . '/lang/pl.php');
        break;
}

// Including the plugin config file, don't delete the following row!
require(__DIR__ . '/pluginconfig.php');
// Including the functions file, don't delete the following row!
require(__DIR__ . '/function.php');
// Including the check_permission file, don't delete the following row!
require(__DIR__ . '/check_permission.php');

$_SESSION["username"] = "disabled_pw"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP version doesn't support `__DIR__` so it's being treated as a literal string.

You can fix it, but you should update your PHP version.

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: updating PHP version is not really trivial task :)
it requires a lot of effofrt

Comment: how  require(__DIR__ . '/lang/en.php');  replace with  dirname(__FILE__) ..@Niet the Dark Absol(how to implement that in my code)

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin Sure, but it's the best solution in the long run. If we can convince everyone to upgrade to PHP7, for instance, then we'll no longer have people complaining that `mysql_fetch_assoc` expects argument 1 to be resource, boolean given.